# Add character escaping in the php file

Tags: php, html, encoding

I have a field named `'name' => $company->name` in my PHP code. Currently, my code is rendering the special characters in the HTML equivalent(screenshot attached). Can anyone please help me to add an escaping to my company name field.

[image: HTML Encode]

Comment: How are you storing and displaying the name? It seems like you must be calling `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`, but you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The [html_entity_decode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) should do the trick:

```
'name' => html_entity_decode($company->name)
```

Alternatively, the [htmlspecialchars_decode function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) can be used too. It all depends on how your strings look like. The former only translate a some special HTML entities back to their respective character representation, while the latter translates all the HTML entities in your string back to characters.